# Laravel - Retrieve result from relation

Tags: laravel

I need some help from anyone to resolve this problem.
I have create a small project in Laravel.
I have two tables: cables and associations.

**cables**
id | cable | price
1   |  OMDS001 | 144.50 
2   |  OMDS001-MC | 152.70 
3   |  OMDS001-NC | 149.00 
4   |  AR-T4CR | 167.90

---

**associations**
cable_id | cable_associated_id

1        |  2
1        |  3

---

The relationship is: **one cable hasMany associaton**
I have to set the **final sale price**. 
The constraint is that if the cables are associated with each other (as 1, 2 and 3), the final selling price of each must be the highest.
In this specific case the final sales prices must be:

1   |  OMDS001 | 152.70 
2   |  OMDS001-MC | 152.70 
3   |  OMDS001-NC | 152.70 
4   |  AR-T4CR | 167.90
The value must be visual only and must not be entered in the database.
Thanks for eventually help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created the corresponding models like `App\Cable` and `App\Association`.

According to the [Laravel Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) you can create the relation in the models like:

**Cable Model**

```
class Cable extends Model {
  public function associations() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Association');
  }

  [...]
}
```

**Association Model**

```
class Association extends Model {
  public function cable() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cable');
  }

  [...]
}
```

In your controller you could iterate over the associations array:

```
$cable = Cable::find($id);

$totalPrice = $cable->price;

foreach($cable->associations as $association) {
  $totalPrice = $totalPrice + $association->price;
}
```

If your relation definitions are correct the `$cable->association` property contains an array with every associated cable.

Please note: This is some pseudo code in which I made some assumptions. For the relations you need to specify the correct foreign key column names in your tables. For details please refer to the mentioned documention of Eloquent ORM.